# Laravel 5.4 View not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

So I'm learning laravel 5.4 through the laracast tutorial serie but I'm stuck in episode 10.
Here is the issue:

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>   View [posts.index] not found.

Here is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function index()
    {
    return view('posts.index');
    }
}
```

And this is my View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Simple test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried all these commands vut the problem remains:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Here is the whole application in a [zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KvrRCDPOBUA0fj2qlAMQvaXHblx5kHp5/view?usp=sharing)
I'm on Manjaro 17, using the homestead container on docker

Comment: Upload it to github, if you want to share the application, noone is going to download a zip file to answer your question.

Comment: what is the file path for your view?

Comment: alright here it is on github: https://github.com/Maydara86/Laravel-5.4-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your view file. The file you have is `index.balde.php` and it should be `index.blade.php`